# Proof check: Filtration $\mathbb F$ is not right-continuous

Tags: solution-verification, continuity, stochastic-processes, filtrations

**Question**

Let $\Omega=C([0,2])$ (set of continious funtions) and $X$ a stochastic process on $\mathbb R$ such that $$X_t(\omega):=\omega(t)$$ with the natural filtration $\mathbb F:=(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ given by $\mathcal F_t:=\sigma(X_s:s\le t)$.

I would like to prove that $\mathbb F$ is not right-continuous.

---

**Proof Attempt**

Let $t>0$ and $S_+^t:=\{\omega \in \Omega:X_t(\omega)>0\}=X^{-1}_t((0,\infty))$, then $S_+^t \in \mathcal F_{0+}$, where $\mathcal F_{0+}:=\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0}\mathcal F_{0+\varepsilon}$, but $S_+^t$ is not $\mathcal F_0$-measurable since $t>0$.

---

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Why is $S_+^t \in \mathcal F_{0+}$?

Comment: Oh, I think I found a mistake in my proof since you asked me. $t$ can't be just bigger than 0 since for $t=1$ $S_+^t \not \in \mathcal F_{0+}$, right? So I would make the following change: $S_+:=\{\omega \in \Omega:X_t(\omega)>0, \forall t>0\}$, now it should be in $\mathcal F_{0+}$, right?

Comment: I think that's on the right track, but that $S_+$ still isn't in $\mathcal F_{0+}$ because it is not in $\mathcal F_t$ for any fixed $t > 0$.

Comment: Ok, I am sure that $S_+^t \in \mathcal F_t$ because this is explained with the definition of the chosen filtration. So then $\tilde S:=\cap_{t>0} S_+^t$ should be in $\mathcal F_{0+}$, is that better?

Comment: Yep, that works!  And how do you know $\bar S \not \in \mathcal F_0$?

Comment: I know that for any fixed $t>0$ $S_+^t\not \in \mathcal F_0$ so the intersection of all $t>0$ can't be in $\mathcal F_0$, correct?

Comment: no, this can't be true since $\omega$ is continuous

Comment: Right, it's possible for the intersection (or union) of two sets not in $\mathcal F$ to be in $\mathcal F$.  For example, if $\mathcal F$ is any $\sigma$-algebra and $A$ is any set, then $A \cap A^c \in \mathcal F$, regardless of whether or not $A$ is in $\mathcal F$.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I am a bit stuck at this point. Can you give me a little hint why $\tilde S \not \in \mathcal F_0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, if we define $\bar S := \bigcap_{t > 0} S^t_+$, then $\bar S \in \mathcal F_{0+}$.  The last step is to verify that $\bar S \not \in \mathcal F_0$.  Since $\mathcal F_0 = \sigma(X_0)$, it is enough to show that there exist $\omega_1, \omega_2 \in \Omega = C([0,2])$ such that $\omega_1(0) = \omega_2(0)$ and $\omega_1 \in \bar S$ but $\omega_2 \not \in \bar S$.  So we can just let $\omega_1(t) := t$ and $\omega_2(t) := -t$.

Comment: I got it now! Thank you for your time and help, I really appreciate it!